# SQL Store different types of objects in a single table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to define a database schema to store a list of "objects" in a table.

The main problem is that I need to have a list of geometric shapes and other kinds of markers in a table, in order to draw them on to a google map.

For example, a circle will have only x,y and radius. A polyline will have a set of points, and a square will have...etc etc...

My first thought was to create 2 related tables like:

**object**

- id
- Name

**object_details**

- id
- object_id (foreign from object)
- attribute_type ( enum cartesian_point, size etc....)
- numeric_attribute_valueA
- numeric_attribute_valueB
- datetime_attribute_value
- etc...

But this is a really ugly and inefficent implementation because I may need to have even more different attribute data types - like text or time or anything else and this will complicate the schema creating mostly empty rows in the object_details table.

What would be a good/clean solution for this?

#### Update:

Reading this question after almost 5 years I'd strongly suggest to consider any Schema-Less database for this kind of problems.

Comment: This sounds like a variation of the age old **[EAV vs Relational Model](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sql+eav+vs+relational+model)** debate. The answer is really going to depend on how many different types of objects you want to store, and how frequently new objects will be added.

Comment: @GarethD Thanks for the reference. Agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to pack the data in some format, store it, and unpack it later for use.  For example, JSON, which is supported by both PHP and JS.  For example in PHP:

```
$shape = array("kind"=>"circle", "cx"=>45,"cy"=>90,"r"=>20);
$json = json_encode($shape, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); // NUMERIC_CHECK doesn't treat numbers as strings
```

SQL:

```
$query = "INSERT into SHAPES set `shape`=>'$json'";
```

You can get back to a PHP array with "json_decode();"

```
$shape = json_decode($json);
```

Also, this format makes it easy to use with ajax and jquery, as your server can deliver the JSON contents directly:

```
$.getJSON("server.php",function(response) {
   console.log("Kind is " + response.kind + ", radius is " + response.r);
});
```

Comment: As my type of object may be a little more generic than a spacial object, i'll go with this idea. Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 2):

I 'd suggest to have a look at the [spatial extensions for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/spatial-extensions.html) and 
 [POSTGIS](http://postgis.net/) extension for postgresql which both support storing multiple types of geometry in a spatial columns.

Comment: In general, the MySQL manual is very good. It's a bit thin when it comes to geometry, but there are tutorials that cover this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using the spatial extensions, you could consider using a text column and populate it with a [GEOJSON](http://geojson.org/) object. It looks like [Google maps can consume GeoJSON](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer), so that might work for you.